# Smoothing an inclined line

Tags: c++, qt, lines

I can't find a proper way to draw a smooth inclined line without having it over-pixelated in Qt with the `QPainterPath` object.

Note that I know it doesn't make sense to draw the path in the `paintEvent` function, I put it there for sake of simplicity. I'm trying to draw the line directly in the central widget.

Hereafter is a snippet of my code:

```
void MyObject::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainterPath aPath;
    aPath.moveTo(40.0, 60.0); //random values to try
    aPath.lineTo(254, 354.0);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(20, 20, 200), 10, Qt::SolidLine));
    painter.drawPath(aPath);
}
```

And here is the result I get:

[image]

It's awful! The only beautiful lines I can draw are horizontal, vertical or 45° inclined ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for drawing quality, the Qt documentation provides an [illustrative example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-painting-concentriccircles-example.html) ([5.X version](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-concentriccircles-example.html)) of the use of its render quality flags. Generally, you can use the [flags specified here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#rendering-quality) ([5.X version](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum)), and set them using the [`QPainter::setRenderHint()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setRenderHint) ([5.X version](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setRenderHints)) function. See if you are able to achieve the desired quality using those methods. For your code, you'd be looking for something like

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing, true);
painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(20, 20, 200), 10, Qt::SolidLine));
painter.drawPath(aPath);
```

Comment: you better include the relevant parts directly in the question. Links can break at any time

Comment: I've added some specific code as an example, but the 1st party Qt documentation goes into much more detail than I can reasonably write out here

Comment: The QPainter::Antialiasing  hint did the trick. Thanks, the result looks now exactly as I wanted.